# Do you want me to not go? or Do you not want me to go? or Don't you want me to go?

Tags: negation

1. Do you want me to not go?
2. Do you not want me to go?
3. Don't you want me to go?

What's the correct way to ask if the other person doesn't want me to go? What is the difference between these three questions? The more I think about the options, the more I get confused. I also don't know which grammar book to refer to know the answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to ask about the differences in meaning of these three sentences, I'll be happy to answer it. The only answer so far already answers about the differences in meaning, rather than which is correct, so it's OK to change the question. Please tag me in a comment when you're done.

Comment: @gotube I have edited the question.I have already got an answer. If you have more to add, please do so as I am really interested in the nuances you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions all have the same overall meaning of "*Do you want me to go?*", but they each have their own *pragmatic meaning*.

> (1) Do you want me to not go?

In question (1), it's understood that the listener wants something, but the asker isn't clear what it is, so the asker is clarifying what they would like.

Someone using the structure *[ "want" + "to not" + base form ]* is more likely to be asking in disbelief, with an undertone of "*Do you really mean that? Are you kidding me?*"

When I read that question without any context, I first imagine a situation like person A suggesting person B skip their own child's birthday party because A wants to spend time with B.

It doesn't always have this nuance, but it's good to be aware of it. It's so common to use this structure with that nuance, that when I don't want to imply disbelief, I expressly say so, like, "*Do you want me to not go? And I don't mean that in the negative way, I just want to be very clear about what you want.*"

> (2) Do you not want me to go?

This is asking if the other person has a preference, and includes the nuance that the asker believes the preference is for them not to go. There's no negative undertone here, just a neutral question.

> (3) Don't you want me to go?

*Negative questions* like this one include the asker's belief that the opposite is true (*I believe you **do** want me to go*), but they're either questioning it now, or they're asking for confirmation that they're right.

Search this site or elsewhere for "negative questions" to learn more about them than I need to go into here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it's very clear now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you want me / to not go: Focus on "not going"
2. Do you not want me / to go: Focus on "not wanting"
3. Don't you want me / to go: The same as #2, but with a contraction ("do not you..."). Weird phrasing when spelled out, but the contraction is a common phrasing in casual speech.

This really just shows how words in English can be arranged differently without really affecting meaning. They may sound a little different, but the words mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: We mainly use the _do you not want..._ form when we had previously presumed, expected, or hoped that the listener did want whatever it is. Do you not want those French fries?

Comment: Thank you so much. The question might sound silly, but for a non native speaker, the grammar rules of sentence construction is sometimes difficult to understand. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do you want me to not go?
> 2. Do you not want me to go?
> 3. Don't you want me to go?

1. Would you prefer that I didn't go?
2. I'm not sure whether you want me to stay or to go.
3. ditto